# Android - reading a samed image (from camera) without outofmemory error

Tags: android, image, decode

I know this has tons of q/a here, and I believe I went through most of them...

But cant find a straight answer that works for me:

I am building an android app. I have a "snapshot.jpg" file that I save from the camera callback (jpegCallback), and it is 640x480.

Now I need to read this file, crop it to 466x466. If I try to read the file as it is (decode...) I get the dreaded OutOfMemory exception.

I know all the solutions here talk about calculating width & height using 'options', and scaling - this is no good for me, because scaling minimum is by 2, and so I get a 320x240, which is far below the resolution I need (466x466)

I cant believe my phone with all that RAM will not handle a 466x466 image...

TIA

Comment: Show us the callback and cropping code? There might be something useful there.

Comment: you can set the resolution of the camera BEFORE you take a picture.